# Ошибка в строке (24) operand types do not match

Tags: ассемблер

Задание : найти максимальное слово в строке и вывести его. Вот мой код, но выдает ошибку в этой строке

```
MOV   DI,buff+2
```

Вот сам код :

```
.model tiny
.stack 256
.data
        sin db  'Enter string:  $'
        buff   label byte          ; буфер для приема строки с клавиатуры (по ф-и 0ah)
        poss   DW  0
        len    DW  0
.386 
Start:
        mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax 

        lea dx, sin
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h     ; приглашение ввести строку

        lea dx, buff
        mov ah, 0ah
        int 21h     ; ввод стркои в буфер

        PUSH  20h 0
           POP   CX  AX          ; AL = 20H (пробел), СХ = 0
           MOV   CL,[buff+1]     ; СХ = длина строки
           MOV   DI,buff+2       ; ..её адрес
        compare:
           PUSH  CX              ; сохраняем текущую позицию символа
           REPNE SCASB           ; ищем пробел в строке
           POP   BX              ; пробел нашёлся! берём нач.позицию символа
           SUB   BX,CX           ; и расчитываем разницу
           CMP   BX,[len]        ; тест с переменной
           JLE   next            ; переход, если длина слова меньше/равно
           MOV   [len],BX        ; иначе - сохраняем в переменных
           MOV   [poss],DI       ;   ..адрес конца слова, и его длинну
        next:
           DB    8,0C9h          ; последний символ в строке? (OR CL,CL)
           JNZ   compare         ; нет - продолжаем искать пробелы

           MOV   CX,[len]        ; длинна самого/длинного слова
           MOV   SI,[poss]
           SUB   SI,CX           ; его позиция в оригинальной строке
        print:
           LODSB                 ; выводим это слово на экран!
           INT   29h
           LOOP  print

           XOR   AX,AX
           INT   16h
           INT   20h

END Start
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить на `MOV   DI, offset buff+2`. Или на `lea di, [buff+2]`.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, помогло)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для masm и tasm нужно явно указывать, что вы хотите записать в регистр адрес (смещение), для этого используется ключевое слово `offset`:

```
MOV DI, offset buff+2
```

Если его не указать, то транслятор может посчитать, что вы хотите в переменную записать содержимое адреса. Т.к. размер элементов буфера у вас указан как байт, то получится ошибка из заголовка вопроса.

Другой вариант - использовать команду `lea` (load effective address - загрузить "эффективный" адрес):

```
lea di, [buff+2]
```

Несмотря на то что в правом операнде указаны квадратные скобки, в левый операнд в любом случае будет записан адрес правого операнда.